# reference request: non-negative quadratic function on a subspace, extended by infinity outside

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I am looking for a reference for some objects that naturally appeared in my research. Suppose $W$ is a subspace of a real vector space $V$, and $f:W \to \mathbb R$ is a non-negative quadratic function on $W$. I want to extend $f$ to take value $\infty$ on the complement of $W$ in $V$. As an example, suppose $V$ is the space of all real sequences and $f(\{a_n\})=\sum |a_n|^2$ (although I am more interested in the finite-dimensional spaces). These seem to be rather natural objects, so I am sure that they were considered before. Any help in locating a reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any substantive difference between considering $f$ to be "infinity" on $V \setminus W$ or considering it to be "undefined", and so I'm not really sure that there's much to be said about these objects in general, much less a book or paper about them. Is there something specific you are hoping to learn about them?

Comment: I don't know about infinite dimensional vector spaces, but in the case of finite dimensional manifolds, what you describe looks like the definition of a subriemannian manifold; see for instance the book https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~davide.barilari/Notes.php For your specific example, as a person with an interest in probability, this gives me an urge of calling your injection an abstract Wiener space (in your case, associated to a sequence of iid standard real Gaussian variables).

Comment: I would just call it "a norm that takes values in $[0,\infty]$". I don't think there's any special literature on this topic.

Comment: @PierrePC :  Thank you for the reference to subriemannian manifolds: I haven't seen them before. I am ultimately looking not just into these "generalized Euclidean spaces", but also into non-expanding linear maps between them. The ultimate motivation is Arakelov theory, so I also have lattices inside these spaces.